# Calling search display controller without touching the search bar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

J have a tableview which is getting its data and a functioning search bar but the sech is taking spage that i need. So i want to hide it and so the search displaycontroller is called with a push of a button. Been trying but cant find how to make the call.